# Failed to reset password laravel when it is uploaded in shared hosting

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

Reset password on my laravel project goes well with mailtrap while still using localhost, but when uploaded to shared hosting when click send password reset link appears message whoops, looks like something went wrong. Anyone has a solution for this? I use the laravel auth defaults

Comment: enable debug and post the error too. it is not a complete information to answer

Comment: local.ERROR: Swift_TransportException: Connection could not be established with host smtp.mailtrap.io [Connection refused #111] in /home/pkbmwidy/ppdb/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/StreamBuffer.php:268

Comment: your mail settings (config) are incorrect.

Comment: The error means that the remote end _refused_ the connection. It could be your host but I'd first verify your `config/mail.php` settings are correct (which ideally should be pulling values from your `.env` file). Make sure your port number is correct...587 perhaps, etc.

Answer (score 0):

change the your `MAIL_DRIVER=mail` in your driver and set it to `USERNAME` and `PASSWORD` to null.

it will send the mails from your server.

I hope this helps